# Why didn’t Darth Vader’s body disappear in Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In the special edition, you see his one-with-the-force ghost, but he didn’t disappear like Obi-Wan or Yoda. Any good explanations as to why this is the case?

Comment: Technically, you see it in the Original version as well, only he's played by Sebastian Shaw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the canon reader [Star Wars: The Story of Darth Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Story_of_Darth_Vader_(2015)) Anakin's body *did* become one with the Force prior to the cremation of his armour.

> As Anakin lay dying, he asked Luke to remove his helmet so that he could look at his son's face with his own eyes. **When Anakin died, his body disappeared into the light side of the Force.** Luke was sad that his father was dead but proud of him too. The light side of the Force had overcome the dark side and Anakin Skywalker had returned.
>   On the forest moon of Endor, Luke burned Vader's armour. All around the galaxy, everyone celebrated the end of Palpatine and his evil Empire.

Note that this is a retcon. In the earlier [film novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel)) his body was explicitly stated to have been on the pyre.

> Luke stood in a forest clearing before a great pile of logs and
>   branches. Lying still and robed, atop the mound, was the lifeless body
>   of Darth Vader. Luke set a torch to the kindling.
>
> As the flames enveloped the corpse, smoke rose from the vents in the
>   mask, almost like a black spirit, finally freed. Luke stared with a
>   fierce sorrow at the conflagration. Silently, he said his last
>   goodbye. He, alone, had believed in the small speck of humanity
>   remaining in his father. That redemption rose, now, with these flames,
>   into the night.

This is no longer considered to be a canon account of the funeral.

Comment: Or is the novel the oddball? I recall when I saw the original version on VHS the armor was clearly empty.

Comment: @Joshua - I don't think you can clearly make out that it's a body burning in the original; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBMqJ9mQKpI

Comment: Oh my worse than I thought. The frames of the angle-shot on the helmet are clearly just the helmet there (if you get the right pause you can see all the way through the flames) and the sideways shots show the full suit.

Comment: @Joshua - I suspect you're mistaking the reflection of the flames for being able to see all the way though the helmet

Comment: Not see through the helmet. See through where the suit should be to the right of the helmet.